# TSQL convert query to return TRUE/FALSE

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

How can I convert this query to return TRUE/FALSE values?

```
SELECT UserID, ResumeID AS PreviouslyViewed FROM MVJ_ProfileViews
WHERE UserID = [User:UserID]
AND ResumeID = [TknParams:ResumeID]
```

Comment: Your current query returns a user's ID and resume ID.  What relationship does this have to TRUE/FALSE?

Comment: I'm trying to determine if `UserID=1` has viewed `ResumeID=1` then return `true` otherwise `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the result

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT UserID, ResumeID AS PreviouslyViewed
    FROM MVJ_ProfileViews
    WHERE UserID = [User:UserID] AND
          ResumeID = [TknParams:ResumeID]
)
THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END AS result
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you!

Comment: It helped you my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT UserID, ResumeID AS PreviouslyViewed
    FROM MVJ_ProfileViews
    WHERE UserID = [User:UserID] AND
          ResumeID = [TknParams:ResumeID])
BEGIN
     SELECT 'TRUE' Result
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     SELECT 'FALSE' Result
END
```